# How to align an element always center in div without giving width to its parent div?

Tags: css

I am trying to align a element center in a div where i am not giving any width to parent div becouse it will spread according to screen size , there is total 3 element in div :

1. Buttons
2. Heading
3. Logo

buttons will always align left and logo will align right whenever screen size will be change and the heading will always align center like this
[image]

My code is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/7AE7J/1/
please let me know where i am going wrong and what css i should apply for getting the element (heading) align center always.

HTML

```
<div  id="header">
     <div id="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="button_back">link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="button_back">link 2</a>
    </div>
        <h1>Heading of the page</h1>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#">
           <img src="http://lorempixum.com/60/60" width="178" height="31" alt="logo" />
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
     background:green;
     height:44px;
    width:100% }

 #buttons {
     float: left;
     margin-top: 7px;
     }

 #buttons a {
     display: block;
     font-size: 13px;
     font-weight: bold;
     height: 30px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color:blue;
    float:left}

 #buttons a.button_back {
     margin-left: 8px;
     padding-left:10px;
     padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right:15px }

 #header h1 {
     color: #EEEEEE;
     font-size: 21px;
     padding-top: 9px ;
     margin:0 auto}

 #logo {
     float: right;
    padding-top: 9px;
     }
```

Comment: Give the parent width:100%; if you're using the margin auto trick this will work.

Comment: @Kyle - I tried but it's not making any difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` for this:

```
#header {
  text-align: center;
}

#header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#header h1 {
    display: inline;
}

#header #buttons {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#header #logo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

`display: inline` is actually a bit more cross-browser than `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Hi Niko, 
I tried whatever you said here , yes now my heading element is center aligned ,but its not working properly ,plz see here http://jsfiddle.net/jamna/LeXN9/4/

Comment: I've updated both the css and the fiddle, see here http://jsfiddle.net/LeXN9/5/ - the #logo needed y-coordinates via the `top` property.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This requires that the element has a given width. Otherwise it takes up the width of the container (i.e. 100%)

Comment: i know, i assumed that the element has a given width.