# aligning elements center in div, not centering

Tags: css, html

I have the following

[image]

I need to get the team names and points centered, under team jerseys.
I have been researching and trying, and tweaking but it just wont get centered.

In my latest attempt I tried help in this post [How to align an element always center in div without giving width to its parent div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537759/how-to-align-an-element-always-center-in-div-without-giving-width-to-its-parent) with display:inline block to no success:

```
.tNames {
    margin-left:0px auto;
    margin-right:0px auto;
    float:left;
}

<div align="center" class="tNames">
<center>
    <label class="blue"><input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team1'].'"><span>'.$team1.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team2'].'"><span>'.$team2.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="draw"><span>Draw</span></label><br />
    </center>';

        echo'BY';
        echo'<select name="score[]" id="winScore">';

            echo'<option value="1">1</option>';
            echo'<option value="2">2</option>';
            echo'<option value="3">3</option>';
            echo'<option value="4">4</option>';
            echo'<option value="5">5</option>';
            echo'<option value="6">6</option>';

            echo'</select>';    
            echo'POINTS';
    echo'</div>';
```

**WITHOUT FLOAT**
[image]

```
.tNames{  
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: `float:left` certainly won't help centering things. Did you try `text-align:center`? Or `display:inline-block; margin:auto;` ?

Comment: Can you post the rendered html code??

Comment: @JeremyThille I did mate, I need that float in there otherwise it does not line up correctly

Comment: You mention you're using `display:inline block`. Was that a typo? Because the correct rule is `display:inline-block` and will horizontally center elements in the parent div unless being overridden by another rule (e.g. float:left shouldn't be there)

Comment: So, you want to center _or_ float left. You can't have both.

Comment: @JeremyThille got it lets give it a go

Comment: @GuruprasadRao will do mate

Comment: I'm bit confused You wanna float your Div and You also want center ?

Comment: if you want to center your inner content, you just remove float:left, and also ```margin-left:0px auto; margin-right:0px auto;``` is wrong code and no use at all

Comment: Also please, post HTML, not PHP, as Guruprasad asked. It's easy to work on HTML, much less on what generates it.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/27gxgfk2/ , I guess your inner content has float attribute or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the `float:left;` which is forcing them to be aligned to the left of the div.

To align them in center you could simply use `display:table;` with `.tNames` and `display:table-row;` with `.tNames labels` which represent the team names, here's what you need:

```css
.tNames {
  margin-left: 0px auto;
  margin-right: 0px auto;
  dsiplay: table;
}
.tNames label {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="tNames">

  <label class="blue">
    <input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team1'].'"><span>'.$team1.'</span>
  </label>
  <br />
  <label class="green">
    <input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team2'].'"><span>'.$team2.'</span>
  </label>
  <br />
  <label class="green">
    <input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="draw"><span>Draw</span>
  </label>
  <br />By
  <select name="score[]" id="winScore">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>points.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of CSS that I normally use for centering things:

```
.center{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20%; /*this can be whatever the width of each team name*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope that helps. The comments are correct, using `float: left;` will of course make the content go to the left rather than be centered. Here's a rough version that I made by removing the PHP from the code you posted:

```css
.tNames>* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tNames">
    <label class="blue"><input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team1'].'"><span>'.$team1.'</span></label>
    <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team2'].'"><span>'.$team2.'</span></label>
    <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="draw"><span>Draw</span></label>
  <select name="score[]" id="winScore">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```